# jQuery, if contains X, do this, but conditional?

Tags: jquery

I have a line being populated by a database that requires different formatting based on what has been entered. There are three types of formats:
line example 1) $3.00
line example 1) two per person $4.95
line example 2) small $5.00 | medium $10.00 | large $15.00

line 1) No changes required
line 2) Need to insert extra space before $
line 3) need to insert extra space before and after | but not before $ (all instances)

I've looked around and tried to piece things together but can't quite get it. Here's what I have so far:

```js
      $('.menu-price-value:contains("$")').each(function() {
        var newText = $(this).html().replace('$', '<span class="space"></span>$');
        $(this).html(newText);
      });

      $('.menu-price-value:contains("|")').each(function() {
        var newText = $(this).html().replace("|", "&nbsp;|&nbsp;");
        $(this).html(newText);
        $('.menu-price-value').addClass('remove-space');
      });
```

Comment: can you pls provide an example of your html-code ? or better a fiddle

Comment: Could have provided sample HTML as well, but +1 anyway for pushing me over the 35k mark :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems

- Javascript string `replace` only replaces the *first match* (bit lame I know). Use a regex with the `g` (global) option to replace all occurances.
- You were targetting all matching classes in the second example (not just the current match)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/evn91m7y/1/

```
  $('.menu-price-value:contains(" $")').html(function () {
      return $(this).html().replace(/\$/g, '<span class="space">                                             </span>$');
  });

  $('.menu-price-value:contains("|")').html(function () {
      return $(this).html().replace(/\|/g, "&nbsp;|&nbsp;");
  }).addClass('remove-space');
```

To avoid running the `$` check on the `|` matches, you can add `:not(contains("|"))` like this:

```
  $('.menu-price-value:contains(" $"):not(:contains("|"))').html(function () {
      return $(this).html().replace(/\$/g, '<span class="space">                                             </span>$');
  });
```

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/evn91m7y/2/

or even just reverse the check order and *chain* the selectors with `.not()` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/evn91m7y/4/

notes:

- You can use a function with `html()`, which replaced the html with the returned value of each element.
- I differentiated between the first example and the others using the fact that the other examples have a space before the `$`. The alternative is to see of the value *starts with* `$` or not.
- I had to add some styling to make your `space` span visible.
- I exaggerated the changes with styling so you could see them more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp to find the pattern you want and then work with the strings:

```
function myparser(text){    
    if (matches=text.match(/^([^|$])+\$(\d+(\.\d+))$/i))
        return matches[1]+"&nbsp;$"+matches[2];
    else if (text.match(/\|/))
    {
        var myArray=text.split("|");
        var toReturn="";
        for (var i in myArray)
        {
            toReturn+=myArray[i]+"&nbsp;"+"|"+"&nbsp;";
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
    else
        return text;
}
```

The function detects the type of string and then return it fixed.

See it working:
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/142Lyqjs/)**